# As long as I can provide a hasher function for my types why I need to specialize std::hash for my types?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

As long as I can provide my `hasher` for my class types why should I specialize `std::hash<my_class_type>`?

I've implemented this example:

```
class Foo;
template<>
class std::hash<Foo>;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::string const& s, int x) : str_(s), x_(x){}
    std::string str()const {return str_;}
    int get_x() const{ return x_;}

private:
    std::string str_;
    int x_{};
    friend bool operator==(Foo const&, Foo const&);
    friend class std::hash<Foo>;
};

bool operator==(Foo const& lhs, Foo const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.str_ == rhs.str_ && lhs.x_ == rhs.x_;
}

size_t hasher(Foo const& f)
{
    return std::hash<std::string>()(f.str()) ^
            std::hash<int>()(f.get_x());
}

namespace std
{
    template <>
    class hash<Foo>
    {
    public:
        using argument_type = Foo;
        using result_type = std::size_t;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& a)const;
    };

    typename hash<Foo>::result_type
    hash<Foo>::operator()(argument_type const& a)const
    {
        return hash<std::string>()(a.str_) ^
                hash<int>()(a.x_);
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::unordered_set<Foo, decltype(hasher)*> u(5, hasher); // needs hasher as template argument and as function argument
    u.insert(Foo{"hi", 100});

    std::unordered_set<Foo> u2; // doesn't need either
    u2.insert(Foo("hi", 100));

    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

- If I run the program the program compiles and works fine. As you can see my `hasher` function does the same thing as in call operator -the member function of the specialization of `std::hash<Foo>` so why I specialize this latter `std::hash` whereas  simple hasher function can be provided?
- Is that for flexibility? for example providing a `hasher` function rather than specializing `std::hash` for my `Foo` type needs to be specified as a template argument and as function argument in an associative container instantiation like `unordered_set` while the latter needn't be for example?

Comment: You proved that you _don't_ need to specialize `std::hash`, so what are you asking? Why it's also an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As long as I can provide my hasher for my class types why should I [*do I need to*] specialize `std::hash<my_class_type>`?

You don't *need* to. Here are some reasons for doing so anyway:

- If your `class` is a part of an API (internal or external doesn't matter) and you are expected to provide users of the `class` the possibility to use it as a *Key* in an unordered container (or for any other reason, hash it), the friendly approach is to specialize `std::hash`. Noone would expect to have to specify a special function to do the hashing for a type that is (probably documented as) hashable.
- Since it's not that much more code than writing the actual hash algorithm (just a little boilerplate) you could also do it for your own sake if you're going to use it more than once or twice. It keeps the code cleaner.

Once you've written the specialization, you don't need the free hash function, so you could just specialize `std::hash` right away (and skip the free hash function completely) if any of the above seems to apply.

One way to make the boilerplate a little shorter is to specialize it using `struct` instead of `class`. The primary class template is

```
namespace std {
    template<class Key>
    struct hash;
}
```

so it also makes perfect sense to do so. Your definition would then be:

```
namespace std {
    struct hash<Foo> {
        using argument_type = Foo;
        using result_type = std::size_t;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& a) const;
    };
}
```

> Is that for flexibility?

Providing the specialization doesn't effect flexibility but it does make it simpler to use.